# ReactNative ScrollView scroll threshold

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I am trying to understand how can I set a threshold for the RN [ScrollView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/scrollview.html#scrollview).

This is because if you have **multiple vertical scrollable View in a horizontal ScrollView** then the scrolling of the Views is very difficult.

So i just need something that holds the horizontal scrolling until the finger swipe horizontally for a certain pixel-span.

Has anyone a clue about how to archive this?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: I'm also getting beaten by this. I have a webview that I want to scroll vertically inside a scrollview that scrolls horizontally. The scrollview steals the gesture in the middle of a vertical scroll on the webview. Bummer... On iOS is working great.

Comment: I'm also having this same problem, as e.g. on Oculus a scrollable element with clickable elements inside prefers to always scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native scroll event in onScrollEnd to get the velocity of the scroll, then only scroll horizontally if it's past a certain amount. On most vertical/horizontal scrolls, most users only scroll in one direction. If you truly want to implement a distance based scroll, you would need to attach a PanResponder to your component and compare the distnaces of the Grant and Release events.